# SQL Server - Find records that have appeared 3 times in last 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize if this has been answered before, but I looked in every way I knew how and could not find it.

I have a table of weekly reports organized like so: [pcname], [pcnumber], [username], [date]

I am trying to retrieve records where [pcname] has repeated 3 times in the last 30 days. Since these are weekly appearances that means 3 times in the last 4 weeks. Each record should display once, or repeat 3 times and I can filter it in excel later (I'll worry about report and formatting later, just trying to get a working query right now). Everything I try gets me results where some rows have duplicates (except for date of course) but some don't. They should either all have duplicates, or none. There may be multiple appearances if [pcname] is the same, but username is not, but if every column but date is the same, there should either be 3 of everything or 1 of everything, unless there is a change in one of the columns that is not [pcname] or [date] of course. Currently I am getting seemingly random duplicates (where every column but [date] is identical) and I cannot figure out why.

For background: the table is of weekly reports sent out by pc security. Everything that shows up on the list is out of compliance. However, we do not address everything on the list because things go out of compliance for a day or two then resolve themselves all the time. Therefor we need only the offenders that are out of compliance for 3 weeks out of the last 4, to let us know that PC is a problem child.

The SQL query I have so far is:

```
SELECT  
    [pcname],
    [Username],
    [column], --from server2
    [column], --from server2
    [column], --from server3
    [column], --from server3
    [DATE] 


FROM [server1].database.schema.table1 
    LEFT JOIN [server2].database.schema.table2 ON Usernamet1 = Usernamet2 
    LEFT JOIN [server3].database.schema.table3 ON table2.[column] = table3.[column]

WHERE [DATE] >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) -28, 0) 
    AND [pcname] IN (SELECT [pcname] FROM [server1].database.schema.table1 GROUP BY [pcname] HAVING COUNT(*) = 3)
--WHERE [DATE] >= DATEADD(Day, -60, getdate())
GROUP BY [DATE], [pcname], [Username], [column1], [column2], [column3], [column4] 
--HAVING COUNT([pcname]) >= 3
```

As you can see, I left in other methods that I commented out just in case you find them useful. Let me know if you need more information. I am working in SQL server 2008.

Comment: You need to give some data as well, I'm not quite clear on what you are looking for.  Also, I suggest taking a look at SQLFiddle.com for setting up your data so people can easily try it out.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to create one tomorrow morning when I get in to work if I don't have an answer by then. Will take some time to mock up the data, and its 3 minutes till close, and I'm exhausted, and insert other excuses :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close but you should not group by `DATE` field as this is the field that will happen multiple times.

```
SELECT  
    [pcname],
    [Username],
    [column1], 
    [column2], 
    [column3], 
    [column4]


FROM [server1].database.schema.table1 
    LEFT JOIN [server2].database.schema.table2 ON Usernamet1 = Usernamet2 
    LEFT JOIN [server3].database.schema.table3 ON table2.[column] = table3.[column]

WHERE [DATE] >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) -28, 0) 
GROUP BY [pcname], [Username], [column1], [column2], [column3], [column4] 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: When I make that change I get the old "Column 'server1.database.schema.table1.[date]' is invalid because it is not part of either an aggregate function or a group by clause"

Comment: Sorry, I left it in the select clause.

Comment: Good lord, that seems to have worked. Will have to do some testing tomorrow morning and come back and give you all my up-votes. Whether it works or not, thank you so much for help.

Comment: You are a life saver. Query works perfectly. Is there any way to still display the date, or even better, the most recent date (last appearance)? I know how to do it in access, but haven't figured it out in SQL yet. No biggie though, I can research that on my own.