# SQL delete rows based on date difference

Tags: sql-server

The situation is quite complicated to express in the title. An example should be much easier to understand.

My table `A`:

```
uid       id      ticket            created_date
001        1       movie     2015-01-23 08:23:16
002       25       TV        2012-01-13 12:02:20
003        1       movie     2015-02-01 07:15:36
004        1       movie     2014-02-15 15:38:40
```

What I need to achieve is to remove duplicate records that appear within 31 days between each other and retain the record that appear first. So the above table would be reduced to `B`:

```
uid       id      ticket            created_date
001        1       movie     2015-01-23 08:23:16
002       25       TV        2012-01-13 12:02:20
004        1       movie     2014-02-15 15:38:40
```

because the 3rd row in `A` were within 31 days of row 1 and it appeared later than row 1 (2015-02-01 vs 2015-01-23), so it gets removed.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: It is a little unclear to me what you are trying to do here. Are you just wanting to remove all rows for each id where the created_date is > 31 days after the most recent created_date for that id? I have to say that a column named id that allows duplicate is a bit of an oxymoron.

Comment: You can refer this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960679/sql-server-find-records-that-have-appeared-3-times-in-last-30-days

Comment: @SeanLange Updated in response to your question. The answer to your question is yes. What actually happens is that new records are inserted into the table every month. Sometimes a record might be changed/updated and a new record with the same id is inserted into the table. Such instances only happen within 31 days of the creation of the old record. I want to remove these duplicates. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Your first step is to find 'duplicate' rows and check dates between them. Are the duplicates based on `id` or `ticket`? I will assume ID: `SELECT id, MIN(uid), MAX(uid), min(created_date), max(created_date), DATEDIFF(d,min(created_date), max(created_date)) DaysDifferent  FROM A GROUP BY id having count(*) > 1`

Comment: "because the 3rd row in A were within 31 days of row 1 and it appeared later than row 1 (2015-02-01 vs 2015-01-23), so it gets removed." Maybe I'm wrong but this rule doesn't also apply on row 4 of A table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach:

```
SELECT A.uid AS uid
INTO #tempA
FROM A 
    LEFT JOIN A AS B
        ON A.id=B.id AND A.ticket=B.ticket
WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND,B.date,A.date) > 0 AND
      DATEDIFF(SECOND,B.date,A.date) < 31*24*60*60;

DELETE FROM A WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #tempA);
```

This is assuming that by 'duplicate records' you mean records that have both identical `id` as well as identical `ticket` fields. If that's not the case you should adjust the `ON` clause accordingly.

Comment: @breezymri I accepted your suggested edit. However, I'm more familiar with MySQL than with SQL Server and I'm not sure that the dates in the `DATEDIFF` are in the right order for what you want. If they are not you will keep the record that appeared last rather than the one that appeared first. Make sure you test that it works as you intended.